# Only one result showing after sql request and while loop

Tags: php, sql, while-loop

For some reason this only shows the last result, instead of showing all.  The SQL works in the workbench, and $roommate is escaped, but the code has been trimmed for posting purposes:

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT(clients.studentFirstName, ' ', clients.studentLastName) AS name, appointments.location, appointments.subLocation, appointments.startTime, appointments.endTime, appointments.date
FROM appointments JOIN clients
ON appointments.clientID = clients.clientID
WHERE CONCAT(clients.studentFirstName, ' ', clients.studentLastName) = '".$roommate."';";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo
    '<table>
        <tr>
            <td>'
                .$row["name"].
            '</td>
            <td>'
            .$row["location"].
            '</td>
            <td>'
                .$row["subLocation"].
            '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>'
                .$row["startTime"].
            ' - </td>
            <td>'
                .$row["endTime"].
            '</td>
            <td>'
                .$row["date"].
            '</td>
        </tr>
    </table>';

}
```

Comment: Where's your `mysql_query()` call? And please, look into using [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc)s for outputtting multiline HTML like that. Multi-line string concatenation is UGLY no matter how you look at it.

Comment: my call is in the actual file, but the SQL isn't the problem, because I am getting the results in workbench...sorry about the ugly formatting, thanks for the resource, I'll definitely read it later tonight

Comment: Ok, if you just didn't include the query call, that's fine. But there's otherwise nothing really wrong with the code you posted. So if it's outputting only one row, then the query is retrieving only one row. use `echo mysql_num_rows($result)` to see just how many got fetched.

Comment: yeah, thats what the guy below said, but it says there are 2 results, and so does workbench...it's just not displaying both

Comment: So what other code did you eliminate before posting? If you do another fetch call WITHIN the while loop, you'd be consuming more of the result set. Or if you're assigning new values to $result, etc...

Comment: Yup, the fetch call was messing with it...trott got to that conclusion maybe a minute before you, mysql_data_seek($result, 0) has fixed the problem...thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysql_num_rows()` to determine the number of rows that were returned by your query.  If it reports that you are only getting 1 result, then you will need to refine your query to get the number of results you intend.

If you're using one of the `mysql_fetch_*` functions before the while loop, that would advance the cursor and make you miss one or more results in your `while` loop.  If that's the case, call `mysql_data_seek($result, 0)` before the `while` loop.

Comment: I am getting 2 results, and if I take it out of the while loop, only the other one shows.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer with an additional speculative suggestion.

Comment: NICE! it worked!  thanks for letting me know about that quirk, I would have never figured it out!